# How to open a particular year and month in PrimeNg's p-calendar on click

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-calendar

How to make PrimeNG Calendar open a particular month of a particular year on click

I want my p-calendar to open a future month on start but it always opens up with current month

so suppose i want my user to select date in 2026,
it will open 2018 and he has to scroll from there.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply bind value to `defaultDate` date like this

```
<p-calendar [inline]="true" defaultDate={{value}}></p-calendar>
```

Comment: i dont know why its not working
the date i am provide to minDate same date i am providing to defaultDate but nothing happens.

Comment: okay it works but can i assign it dynamically as in change its value?